# How to redirect to outlook mail with a recipient added in javascript?

Tags: javascript, email, redirect, outlook, frontend

In gmail i can add the recipients in the link and it will direct to compose mail as written below

```
let email = "alexmurphy98@gmail.com";
let link = `https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=${email}`;
```

Then in an anchor tag to use that link

```
 <a href=`${link}` target="_blank">gmail</a>
```

My question is how can i do the same thing in outlook?As their compose does not contain any link.

Comment: This seems to be answered here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlookcom-compose-link/88f2d397-d7ca-4db2-b6a4-163a754074d7

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,i have seen that post too ,but that was an old post and after outlook opted for react(before it was asp.net) ,those links stopped working.

Comment: Well that’s annoying. I’ll keep looking, but your best bet is probably to look up outlook online documentation.

Comment: thanks dude,i will look into it ,if you find any kind of solution ,let me know here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this seems to be working fine.

```
https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/deeplink/compose?to=your@email.com
```